# Merge PDF Files in subfolders raises FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, pdf

In my case, I have a main folder "Documents" and inside the folder there are subfolders. Inside the subfolders, there pdf files that I am seeking to merge into one pdf file for each sub folder
Here's my try till now

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

myDirectory = 'Documents'
mylist = list(map(lambda x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(myDirectory), x),os.listdir(myDirectory)))

for d in mylist:
    print(d)
    sFolder = os.path.basename(d)

    x = [a for a in os.listdir(d) if a.endswith('.pdf')]
    merger = PdfFileMerger()

    for pdf in x:
        merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))

    with open(sFolder + '.pdf', 'wb') as fout:
        merger.write(fout)
```

When executing the code, I encountered an error like that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 30, in <module>
    merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2600-002947-374.pdf'
```

How can I fix such an error? Is the cause of the error the names of the pdf files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change only this part:

```
for pdf in x:
    merger.append(open(os.path.join(d, pdf), 'rb'))
```

The complete code below worked for me.

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

myDirectory = 'Documents'
mylist = list(map(lambda x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(myDirectory), x),os.listdir(myDirectory)))

for d in mylist:
    print(d)
    sFolder = os.path.basename(d)

    x = [a for a in os.listdir(d) if a.endswith('.pdf')]
    merger = PdfFileMerger()

    for pdf in x:
        merger.append(open(os.path.join(d, pdf), 'rb'))

    with open(sFolder + '.pdf', 'wb') as fout:
        merger.write(fout)
```